Can you adjust baked f-curve timings?
I baked a bunch of f-curve sound samples. But I need them to play later and I don't want to rebake all of them again. Is it possible to slide this to the right?


If you select the channel and then go to the Channel menu, select Samples to Keys and the curve gets converted to keyframes. These can be selected and moved around just like all other keyframes (press G and then X to make sure you only move them horizontally). If you want to make sure to not accidentally mess them up after moving, you can find Keys to Samples in the menu as well to convert them back.

